# String mode aggregation with group by function

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby, mode

I have dataframe which looks like below

```
Country  City
UK       London
USA      Washington
UK       London
UK       Manchester
USA      Washington
USA      Chicago
```

I want to group country and aggregate on the most repeated city in a country

My desired output should be like

```
Country City
UK      London
USA     Washington
```

Because London and Washington appears 2 times whereas Manchester and Chicago appears only 1 time.

I tried

> ```
> from scipy.stats import mode
> df_summary = df.groupby('Country')['City'].\
>                         apply(lambda x: mode(x)[0][0]).reset_index()
> ```

But it seems it won't work on strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate your error, but you can use [`pd.Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html), which accepts strings and returns a series, using [`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) to extract the first value:

```
res = df.groupby('Country')['City'].apply(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]).reset_index()

print(res)

  Country        City
0      UK      London
1     USA  Washington
```

Comment: which means should I have to import pd.Series.mode ?

Comment: @MosesSoleman, Nope, you are using `pd.Series.mode` whenever you use `x.mode()`, i.e. you don't need to import anything extra.

Comment: Thanks , it works on this sample set , but let me try on a bigger set.

Comment: when I try with bigger set which has many unique value I get this error index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: @MosesSoleman, Can you edit your question to include data that replicates the error?

Comment: jpp, Your solution works actually there was a problem with my dataset , after I fixed , it worked. thank You.

Comment: @MosesSoleman,  you can also try `scipy` which works fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

try like  below:

```
>>> df.City.mode()
0        London
1    Washington
dtype: object
```

OR

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
```

Can use `scipy` with `stats` + `lambda` :

```
df.groupby('Country').agg({'City': lambda x:stats.mode(x)[0]})
               City
Country
UK           London
USA      Washington

#  df.groupby('Country').agg({'City': lambda x:stats.mode(x)[0]}).reset_index()
```

However, it gives nice count as well if you don't want to return ony First value:

```
>>> df.groupby('Country').agg({'City': lambda x:stats.mode(x)})
                        City
Country
UK           ([London], [2])
USA      ([Washington], [2])
```